# I have a set/venn diagram which I cannot solve.

Tags: measurable-sets

I have two sets:

|A| = 13
|B| = 26
|AUB| = 32 (U is the universal set)
|U| = 50

Given the following information, label the Venn diagram, with the appropriate number of elements in each attribute.

I want to use this equation -> |AUB| = |A| + |B| - |A intersection B|

I solved this -> 32 = 13 + 26 - |A intersection B|

Now I am stuck.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle): compute $A \cap B$.

Comment: Why are you stuck? $32=39-|A\cap B|\iff|A\cap B|=39-32$.

Comment: Do you know [how to solve linear equations in one variable](https://openstax.org/books/college-algebra-2e/pages/2-2-linear-equations-in-one-variable)? You need to transpose the number to the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find $|A|-|A\cap B|,\ |B|-|A\cap B|,\ |A\cap B|,\  |U|-|A \cup B|
$ and put the numbers in their places [image]

you said you can find and solve for $|A \cap B|$ so it is not so hard to find $A|-|A\cap B|,\ |B|-|A\cap B|,\ |A\cap B|,\  |U|-|A \cup B|$